# Calculating number of moves from top left corner to bottom right with move in any direction

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a problem asked to me in an interview, this is a similar problem I found so I thought of asking here. The problem is

> There is a robot situated at (1,1) in a N X N grid, the robot can move in any direction left, right ,up and down. Also I have been given an integer k, which denotes the maximum steps in the path. I had to calculate the number of possible ways to move from (1,1) to (N,N) in k or less steps.

I know how to solve simplified version of this problem, the one with moves possible in only right and down direction. That can be solved with Dynamic Programming. I tried applying the same technique here but I don't think it could be solved using 2-dimensional matrix, I tried a similar approach counting possible number of ways from left or up or right and summing up in down direction, but the problem is I don't know number of ways from down direction which should also be added. So I go in a loop. I was able to solve this problem using recursion, I could recurse on (N,N,k) call for up, left and k-1, sum them up but I think this is also not correct, and if it could be correct it has exponential complexity. I found problems similar to this so I wanted to know what would be a perfect approach for solving these types of problems.

Comment: related (though not dupe!) : The same question when only 2 directions are available: [Algorithm for finding all paths in a NxN grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105699/algorithm-for-finding-all-paths-in-a-nxn-grid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have an NxN matrix, where each cell gives you the number of ways to move from (1,1) to (i,j) in exactly k steps (some entries will be zero). You can now create an NxN matrix, where each cell gives you the number of ways to move from (1,1) to (i,j) in exactly k+1 steps - start off with the all-zero matrix, and then add in cell (i,j) of the previous matrix to cells (i+1, j), (i, j+1),... and so on.

The (N,N) entry in each of the k matrices gives you the number of ways to move from (1,1) to (i,j) in exactly k steps - all you have to do now is add them all together.

```
Here is an example for the 2x2 case, where steps outside the 
matrix are not allowed, and (1,1) is at the top left.
In 0 steps, you can only get to the (1,1) cell:

1 0
0 0

There is one path to 1,1. From here you can go down or right,
so there are two different paths of length 1:

0 1
1 0

From the top right path you can go left or down, and from the
bottom left you can go right or up, so both cells have paths
that can be extended in two ways, and end up in the same two
cells. We add two copies of the following, one from each non-zero
cell

1 0
0 1


giving us these totals for paths of length two:

2 0
0 2

There are two choices from each of the non-empty cells again 
so we have much the same as before for paths of length three.

0 4
4 0

Two features of this are easy checks:

1) For each length of path, only two cells are non-zero, 
corresponding to the length of the path being odd or even.

2) The number of paths at each stage is a power of two, because
each path corresponds to a choice at each step as to whether to 
go horizontally or vertically. (This only holds for this simple 
2x2 case).
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to construct a matrix which gives me the number of ways to move from (1,1) to (i,j) in exactly k steps?

Comment: The pseudocode would be very similar to Thomas's (except that I am slightly worried that trying to combined the matrices might produce some double counting) so I tried to work through an example to see what is going on.

Comment: Could you please spare a bit of time to explain this solution to me. I could be on chat on a time that suits you?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: This algorithm is **incorrect**. See the comments and mcdowella's answer. However, the corrected algorithm does not make a difference to the time complexity.

---

It can be done in O(k * N^2) time, at least. Pseudocode:

```
# grid[i,j] contains the number of ways we can get to i,j in at most n steps,
# where n is initially 0
grid := N by N array of 0s
grid[1,1] := 1
for n from 1 to k:
  old := grid
  for each cell i,j in grid:
    # cells outside the grid considered 0 here
    grid[i,j] := old[i,j] + old[i-1,j] + old[i+1,j] + old[i,j-1] + old[i,j+1]
return grid[N,N]
```

There might be an O(log k * (N*log N)^2) solution which is way more complex. Each iteration through the outer `for` loop is nothing but a convolution with a fixed kernel. So we can convolve the kernel with itself to get bigger kernels that fuse multiple iterations into one, and use FFT to compute the convolution.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, could you tell me how would I be able to find number of ways from (1,1) to (N,N) using this matrix? for any k

Comment: After `k` iterations, the value you are looking for is in `grid[N,N]`, which is returned in the last statement of my code.

Comment: (I have added a comment on my answer that I worry that trying to use just one matrix for all this - although it obviously saves a lot of store - might cause some double counting. Is it possible that the two answers are in fact returning different answers, or using different definitions of what is being counted?)

Comment: Thanks mcdowella, you are right! My code is wrong, because I assumed that "at most n steps" is the same as "n steps, in some of which we don't move". But the counts are different. If we are asked how many ways there are to move one square to the right in at most two steps, your answer is 1 but mine is 2 (rest, then step; or step, then rest).

Comment: Glad we agree - I really like the FFT trick, by the way. If I'd thought about applying FFT I'd have stopped after seeing it doesn't by much for a single step - applying it to update several steps in one is something I'll try and remember.

Answer (score 0):

Basically uniquepaths( row, column ) = 0 if row > N || column > N
                                       1 if row ==N && column == N
                                       uniquepaths(row+1, column) + uniquePaths(row, column+1)
i.e, the solution have optimal substructure and overlapped subproblems. So, it can be solved using Dynamic Programming. Below is memorization (lazy/on demand) version of it (related which basically returns paths as well: [Algorithm for finding all paths in a NxN grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105699/algorithm-for-finding-all-paths-in-a-nxn-grid/25095973#25095973)) (you may refer to my blog for more details: http://codingworkout.blogspot.com/2014/08/robot-in-grid-unique-paths.html)

```
private int GetUniquePaths_DP_Memoization_Lazy(int?[][] DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache, int row, 
            int column)
        {
            int N = DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache.Length - 1;
            if (row > N)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (column > N)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if(DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache[row][column] != null)
            {
                return DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache[row][column].Value;
            }
            if((row == N) && (column == N))
            {
                DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache[N][N] = 1;
                return 1;
            }
            int pathsWhenMovedDown = this.GetUniquePaths_DP_Memoization_Lazy(DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache,
                row + 1, column);
            int pathsWhenMovedRight = this.GetUniquePaths_DP_Memoization_Lazy(DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache,
                row, column + 1);
            DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache[row][column] = pathsWhenMovedDown + pathsWhenMovedRight;
            return DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache[row][column].Value;
        }
```

**where the caller is**

```
int GetUniquePaths_DP_Memoization_Lazy(int N)
        {
            int?[][] DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache = new int?[N + 1][];
            for(int i =0;i<=N;i++)
            {
                DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache[i] = new int?[N + 1];
                for(int j=0;j<=N;j++)
                {
                    DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache[i][j] = null;
                }
            }
            this.GetUniquePaths_DP_Memoization_Lazy(DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache, row: 1, column: 1);
            return DP_Memoization_Lazy_Cache[1][1].Value;
        }
```

**Unit Tests**

```
[TestCategory(Constants.DynamicProgramming)]
        public void RobotInGridTests()
        {
            int p = this.GetNumberOfUniquePaths(3);
            Assert.AreEqual(p, 6);
            int p1 = this.GetUniquePaths_DP_Memoization_Lazy(3);
            Assert.AreEqual(p, p1);
            var p2 = this.GetUniquePaths(3);
            Assert.AreEqual(p1, p2.Length);
            foreach (var path in p2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("===================================================================");
                foreach (Tuple<int, int> t in path)
                {
                    Debug.Write(string.Format("({0}, {1}), ", t.Item1, t.Item2));
                }
            }
            p = this.GetNumberOfUniquePaths(4);
            Assert.AreEqual(p, 20);
            p1 = this.GetUniquePaths_DP_Memoization_Lazy(4);
            Assert.AreEqual(p, p1);
            p2 = this.GetUniquePaths(4);
            Assert.AreEqual(p1, p2.Length);
            foreach (var path in p2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("===================================================================");
                foreach (Tuple<int, int> t in path)
                {
                    Debug.Write(string.Format("({0}, {1}), ", t.Item1, t.Item2));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be infinite no of ways. This is because you can form an infinite loop of positions and thus infinite possibilities. For ex:- You can move from (0,0) to (0,1) then to (1,1), then (1,0) and back again to (0,0). This forms a loop of positions and thus anyone can go round and round these types of loops and have infinite possibilities.