# Algorithm to find appropriate-and-correct destination

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

> A robot lands on Mars, which happens to be a cartesian grid; assuming that we hand the robot these instructions, 
>       such as LFFFRFFFRRFFF, where "L" is a "turn 90 degrees left", "R" is a "turn 90 degrees right", and "F" is "go forward one space, 
>       please write control code for the robot such that it ends up at the appropriate-and-correct destination, and include unit tests.

Here is an example output with command "FF":

```
[0, 2]
```

I could find solution to this problem on Google, but I am not very clear with the explanation. I am trying to clearly understand the logic on how to solve this and implement in Java. Any help is appreciated.

Update: This is an interview question. For now, I trying improve my knowledge. It is interesting question to me. I can remove if i am breaking any stack over rule.

Here is the research I did:
[Is there an equivalent of Scala's Either in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162407/is-there-an-equivalent-of-scalas-either-in-java-8)

[Algorithm for finding all paths in a NxN grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105699/algorithm-for-finding-all-paths-in-a-nxn-grid)

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-sequence-of-moves-for-a-robot-is-circular-or-not/

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy If you read the task three or more times, you would get the surprizing answer: Yes, it is and it is obvious.

Comment: I hate to give hints on this if this interview question is TO BE ANSWERED.

Comment: Tell me reason why you vote -1. I can remove question. I am trying to find answer for everyone.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy I already said to employer I am not able to solve this else upwork can help to get this but I am trying to know . I am not try to cheat and get job. that's something I don't do and will never do.

Comment: @BostonStar Which particular part do you have trouble understanding? Draw a normal X, Y coordinate system, X-axis going right, Y-axis going up. Place robot at `0,0` and make it face up. `F` moves forward 1, leaving robot at `0,1`. Another `F` moves forward 1, leaving robot at `0,2`. `L` turns robot left. `F` moves forward 1, leaving robot at `-1,2`. And so on. Now, starting at `0,0`, where does `LFFFRFFFRRFFF` leave the robot?

Comment: To follow I think aswer is [3,6] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared for you the following code:

```
public static String calculate(String str) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int[][] move = {{0,1}, {1,0}, {-1,0}, {0,-1}};
    int dir = 0;

    for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == 'F') { 
            x += move[dir][0]; 
            y += move[dir][1]; 
        } else if (ch == 'L') {
            dir++;
        } else if (ch == 'R') {
            dir--;
        }
        dir = (dir + 4) % 4;
    }
 return "[" + x + ", " + y + "]";
 }
```

Let's analyse my naïve solution.

- `int[][] move = {{0,1}, {1,0}, {-1,0}, {0,-1}};` is all the combinations of movement when you rotate to left led with variable `dir`.
- Loop the `String str` to get the each command
- Read the command and in case of `F`, move torwards in the direction `dir`. Subarray is for the axis.
- In case of rotating, add or subtract the `dir` for the correct result.
- Finally make the `dir` to not overflow with `dir = (dir + 4) % 4;`. It means when I move down `dir = 0` and I go left (`dir--`), it will lead `dir=-1`, that is illegal. So `dir + 4 = 3` and `3 % 4 = 3`, it gives the last set of direction.

Hope it helps and you understand now the logics.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is not about interview question. It is about how to think for such solution.

Comment: I made this comment because community member vote negative without understanding.

Comment: Welcome, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Run{
    public static void main(String []args){
        int angle = 0, c = 0;
        int[] coords = {0,0};
        String d;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input your command");
        d = in.nextLine();
        for (c = 0; c < d.length; c++){
            if (d[c] == 'R'){
                 angle = (angle + 90)%360;
            }else if (d[c] == 'L'){
                 angle = (angle + 270)%360;
            }else if (d[c] == 'F'){
                 switch(angle){
                      case 0: coords[1]++;break;
                      case 90: coords[0]++;break;
                      case 180: coords[1]--;break;
                      case 270: coords[0]--;
                }
            }
         }
         System.out.println('['+coords[0]+','+coords[1]+']');
    }
}
```

I think this code is simple enough.
Currently I have no Java environment, so I cannot test it. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Super Cool handsome,your logic is correct based on my opinion, I tested your code , i found some errors, your *string **d*** need to convert **array** before for loop *

> in.nextLine().toCharArray()

*;  and string d will be ***char[]d*** . Also your print output i have changed

> ("["+coords[0]+","+coords[1]+"]")

. here is my full code which I did.After that it was working